# In Sinatra, is there a way to use my own error handler for some errors, and the default handler for all other errors?

Tags: sinatra, rack

The problem is that the default handler is defined in **Sinatra::ShowExceptions**, which is controlled by the **:raise_errors** configuration setting, and this setting is all or nothing. If **:raise_errors** is off then the **error** method can be used in the Sinatra app, but it has to be used for all exceptions, and there is no access to the error handler defined in **Sinatra::ShowExceptions**. If it is on, then all exceptions get handled by the ShowExceptions middleware.

The rationale for what I want to do is that, at least during development, I want "expected" errors to be handled in a user-friendly fashion and I want "unexpected" errors to be handled in a developer-friendly fashion.

I'm guessing that the only way to do this is to define a rack middleware class that inherits from **Sinatra::ShowExceptions**, and which has some extra option in its **use** method to specify which classes of exceptions to handle or not handle.

Is there any easier way that I am missing?

(I'm using jruby, if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 7):

I found that this seems to work:

```
set :raise_errors, false
set :show_exceptions, false

...

error BaseErrorClassForMySpecialErrors do
  # ... special handling for sub-classes of this error class
end

$showExceptions = Sinatra::ShowExceptions.new(self)

error do
  @error = env['sinatra.error']
  $showExceptions.pretty(env, @error)
end
```

In other words, set **:raise_errors** and **:show_exceptions** to **false** to turn off the ShowExceptions handling of errors, then create a separate instance of **Sinatra::ShowExceptions**, and call its **pretty** method in the **error do** catch-all error handler.

Hopefully creating an extra instance of **Sinatra::ShowExceptions** for this purpose doesn't have any unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I've used set :show_exceptions, :after_handler just for this case.
I've also set :dump_errors, false in development since otherwise errors are dumped even when handled by error block.